# How to start nginx in alpine?

Tags: nginx, alpine-linux

I'm in alpine system and I have installed nginx. But when I try to start `nginx`, I get this error:

```
/run # /etc/init.d/nginx start
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks: Read-only file system
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start nginx as networking would not start
/run #
```

What seems to be the issue? How does `touch /run/openrc/softlevel` help with this situation?

Answer (score 3):

just

```
nginx
```

to stop

```
nginx -s stop
```

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue with starting docker service by openrc on Alpine 3.13.4:

```
host:~# service docker start
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
 * ERROR: sysfs failed to start
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
 * ERROR: cgroups failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start docker as sysfs would not start
```

The sequence that worked:

```
host:~# openrc boot
 * Starting Docker Daemon ...                                                                                     [ ok ]
host:~# service docker status
 * status: started
```

Answer (score 1):

I make a `boos.sh` like this.

```sh
openrc
rc-service nginx start
```

It works.

Comment: this really works. !

Answer (score -1):

You should run it as root, try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```